# It is possible to create a map with rtabmap using the laser and obtaining 3D point cloud at the same time?

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-kinetic, rgbd, 3d-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm using rtabmap in order to carry out rgbd slam using a rgbd camera, odometry and a fake laser scan obtained from the rgbd camera. When I execute rtabmap, the generated grid_map is different if I set grid/fromDepth parameter to true or false.

If a set grid/fromDepth parameter to false, the map is created using the laser scan data, and the map obtained is good. However, if I try to visualize the cloud_map in rviz or saving this point cloud to a pcd file, only the points of the laser scan are visualized/saved.

On the other hand, if I set grid/fromDepth to true, I can visualize the complete 3D point cloud from cloud_map in rviz, and the pcd saved contains the complete point cloud. However, the generated grid_map is not too good, because is generated using all the points, not only the laser scan information.

Is there any way of creating the grid_map only using the laser scan information, and obtaining the complete 3D point cloud in cloud_map at the same time?

Thank you very much in advanced!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/321296/it-is-possible-to-create-a-map-with-rtabmap-using-the-laser-and-obtaining-3d-point-cloud-at-the-same-time?/) by [Rosbq](https://answers.ros.org/users/40459/rosbq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2019-04-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, you cannot have both online outputs at the same time. However, you can generate the 3D point cloud offline by opening the resulting database with `rtabmap` standalone or [rtabmap-databaseViewer](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap/wiki/Tools#database-viewer), then see "File-> Export clouds" menu option.

cheers,
Mathieu

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2019-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rosbq](https://answers.ros.org/users/40459/rosbq/) on 2019-04-18**:
Hi Mathieu,

Thank you very much for you quick answer!

Cheers,
Blanca